# How to add background service in Geofence android

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing, android-geofence, geofire

I am trying to create a geofence with background service for monitor. The geofence create successfully and work when apps Activity is open but when close the app geofence not work. What should I do now. My code is:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyLocation");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    mVerticalSeekBar = (VerticalSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.verticalSeekBar);

    setUpdateLocation();

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (checkPlayService()) {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    displayLocation();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void setUpdateLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        if (checkPlayService()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
            displayLocation();
        }
    }
}

private void displayLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    mLastLocaiton = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocaiton != null) {
        final double latitude = mLastLocaiton.getLatitude();
        final double longitude = mLastLocaiton.getLongitude();

        geoFire.setLocation("You", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                if (mCurrent != null)
                    mCurrent.remove();
                mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title("You"));
                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12);
                mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            }
        });

        Log.d("MRF", String.format("Your last location was chaged: %f / %f", latitude, longitude));
    } else {
        Log.d("MRF", "Can not get your location.");
    }
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean checkPlayService() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICE_RESULATION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This Device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng dangerous_area = new LatLng(23.7424236, 90.3942189);
    mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(dangerous_area)
            .radius(100)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .fillColor(0x220000FF)
            .strokeWidth(5.0f));

    //add GeoQuery here
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(dangerous_area.latitude, dangerous_area.longitude), 0.1f);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s entered the dangerous area",key));
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s exit the dangerous area",key));
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.d("MOVE", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area [%f/%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR", ""+error);
        }
    });
}

private void sendNotification(String title, String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    manager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdate();
}

private void startLocationUpdate() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocaiton = location;
    displayLocation();
}
```

github link is: https://github.com/Farhad2015/Geofence-GeoFire/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mahmud/geotesting/MapsActivity.java

Please help me to create a background service for monitor geofence from background.

Comment: just create a background service and manage background service using job scheduler to revoke android service in background . may be its work for you  follow this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Android Oreo you can't create a long running service as background service. So you have to create a foreground service which the service must bind to the current Activity

Another problem is the location update. When you using `geoQuery` inside a service you have to update location also in the service.  When a location update trigger you must pass this update to activity then only the UI can update. In my solution I am using an interface to update the UI. You can also use broadcast listeners.

When you create service and bind it to activity, then you can use Geofence inside service

```
 public void startService(LatLng latLng, double radius) {
        if (!isServiceRunning) {
            isServiceRunning = true;

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "startTimer request for an already running timer");

        }
        if (geoQuery!=null){
            geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
        }
        geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 2f);
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s entered the dangerous area", key));
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s exit the dangerous area", key));
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Log.d("MOVE", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area [%f/%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "" + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

You can call this method from your activity as

```
  geoService.startService(dangerous_area,2000);
```

This will work even if your app is destroyed.

**The complete code is as follows**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private GoogleMap mMap;
    //Play Service Location
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7192;
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RESULATION_REQUEST = 300193;

    private Location mLastLocaiton;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;


    Marker mCurrent;
    VerticalSeekBar mVerticalSeekBar;
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GeoService geoService;
    private boolean serviceBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.



        mVerticalSeekBar = (VerticalSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.verticalSeekBar);
        mVerticalSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(progress), 1500, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (checkPlayService()) {
                        geoService.buildGoogleApiClient();
                        geoService.createLocationRequest();
                        geoService.displayLocation();
                        geoService.setLocationChangeListener(new GeoService.LocationChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
                                if (mCurrent != null)
                                    mCurrent.remove();
                                mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                                        .title("You"));
                                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12);
                                mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setUpdateLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            if (checkPlayService()) {
                geoService.buildGoogleApiClient();
                geoService.createLocationRequest();
                geoService.displayLocation();
                geoService.setLocationChangeListener(new GeoService.LocationChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
                        if (mCurrent != null)
                            mCurrent.remove();
                        mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                                .title("You"));
                        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12);
                        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean checkPlayService() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICE_RESULATION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This Device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng dangerous_area = new LatLng(8.5324236, 76.8842189);
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(dangerous_area)
                .radius(2000)
                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                .fillColor(0x220000FF)
                .strokeWidth(5.0f));

        geoService.startService(dangerous_area,2000);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting and binding service");
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GeoService.class);
        startService(i);
        bindService(i, mConnection, 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (serviceBound) {
            // If a timer is active, foreground the service, otherwise kill the service
            if (geoService.isServiceRunning()) {
                geoService.foreground();
            } else {
                stopService(new Intent(this, GeoService.class));
            }
            // Unbind the service
            unbindService(mConnection);
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback for service binding, passed to bindService()
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Service bound");
            }
            GeoService.RunServiceBinder binder = (GeoService.RunServiceBinder) service;
            geoService = binder.getService();
            serviceBound = true;
            // Ensure the service is not in the foreground when bound
            geoService.background();
            setUpdateLocation();
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Service disconnect");
            }
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    };


    public static class GeoService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private Location mLastLocation;
        private DatabaseReference ref;
        private GeoFire geoFire;
        private LocationChangeListener mLocationChangeListener;
        private static final String TAG = GeoService.class.getSimpleName();


        // Is the service tracking time?
        private boolean isServiceRunning;

        // Foreground notification id
        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

        // Service binder
        private final IBinder serviceBinder = new RunServiceBinder();
        private GeoQuery geoQuery;

        public class RunServiceBinder extends Binder {
            GeoService getService() {
                return GeoService.this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Creating service");
            }
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyLocation");
            geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
            isServiceRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Starting service");
            }
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Binding service");
            }
            return serviceBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Destroying service");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Starts the timer
         */
        public void startService(LatLng latLng, double radius) {
            if (!isServiceRunning) {
                isServiceRunning = true;

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "startService request for an already running Service");

            }
            if (geoQuery!=null){
                geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
            }
            geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 2f);
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s entered the dangerous area", key));
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                    sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s exit the dangerous area", key));
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Log.d("MOVE", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area [%f/%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "" + error);
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Stops the timer
         */
        public void stopService() {
            if (isServiceRunning) {
                isServiceRunning = false;
                geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "stopTimer request for a timer that isn't running");
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return whether the service is running
         */
        public boolean isServiceRunning() {
            return isServiceRunning;
        }


        /**
         * Place the service into the foreground
         */
        public void foreground() {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
        }

        /**
         * Return the service to the background
         */
        public void background() {
            stopForeground(true);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a notification for placing the service into the foreground
         *
         * @return a notification for interacting with the service when in the foreground
         */
        private Notification createNotification() {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Service is Active")
                    .setContentText("Tap to return to the Map")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            return builder.build();
        }

        private void sendNotification(String title, String content) {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content);

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            manager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            displayLocation();
            startLocationUpdate();
        }

        private void startLocationUpdate() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            displayLocation();
        }

        interface LocationChangeListener {
            void onLocationChange(Location location);
        }

        private void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
        }

        private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        private void displayLocation() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                geoFire.setLocation("You", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        if (mLocationChangeListener!=null) {
                            mLocationChangeListener.onLocationChange(mLastLocation);
                        }
                    }
                });

                Log.d("MRF", String.format("Your last location was chaged: %f / %f", latitude, longitude));
            } else {
                Log.d("MRF", "Can not get your location.");
            }
        }

        public void setLocationChangeListener(LocationChangeListener mLocationChangeListener) {
            this.mLocationChangeListener = mLocationChangeListener;
        }
    }

}
```

Don't forget to add service into manifest

```
  <service android:name=".MapsActivity$GeoService" />
```

Full source code [github.com/vinayakb73/GeoFence-GeoFire](http://github.com/vinayakb73/GeoFence-GeoFire)

Comment: can you post me full code....I am little confused in you answer. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I already added the complete code. just copy & replace  entire MapsActivity into your project's MapsActivity.

Comment: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.mahmud.geotesting. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.  -- this error occur when run the code.

Comment: I don't know what is that error. Please download full source code from my repo then run it . https://github.com/vinayakb73/GeoFence-GeoFire

Comment: when I go to other activity and and back to the MapActivity - it gives another notification. I want one notification if enter or exit from geofence when App is active. hope you understand. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: That's Because in Orea devices you can't run a  background services . Only foreground services are allowed. that's why I put that notification

Comment: I understand. Thank you.